# JDBC ARRAY(ORACLE CollectionTYPE) use String Value Encoding in JAVA

Tags: character-encoding, ojdbc

I'm not good at English

and my English is Grammar is wrong

wish for understanding

I am using ARRAY CLASS in OJDBC6.

Use it(ARRAY class)  to send data to oracle database(procedure).

Data of number type and date type is very well in oracle.

**Howerver data of varchar2 type is null in oracle (ARRAY)**

I see diffrent solution (java path setup orai18n.jar file)
but it have error of java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: oracle.i18n.text.converter.CharacterConverterOGS.getInstance(I)Loracle/i18n/text/converter/CharacterConverter;

I don't found A solution to this problem

Please How to solve this problem ~~  ~~

I use JDK1.7,OJDBC6.jar

----------------------------------------------orclae code----------------------------------
CREATE OR REPLACE
TYPE XXXXXXXX_TYPE AS OBJECT(

```
 nnnnnnn1                NUMBER
,nnnnnnn2                NUMBER
,nnnnnnn3                NUMBER
,vvvvvvv1                VARCHAR2(150)
,nnnnnnn4                NUMBER
,dddddddd1               DATE
,vvvvvvv2                VARCHAR2(250)
,nnnnnnn5                NUMBER
,dddddddd2               DATE
,nnnnnnn6                NUMBER
,dddddddd3               DATE
,nnnnnnn7                NUMBER
,vvvvvvv3               VARCHAR2(10)
,vvvvvvv4               VARCHAR2(30)
,vvvvvvv5               VARCHAR2(20)
,vvvvvvv6               VARCHAR2(80)
```

--XXXXXXXX_TYPE end

CREATE OR REPLACE
TYPE XXXXXXXXXXX_TBL AS TABLE OF XXXXXXXX_TYPE

-- XXXXXXXXXXX_TBL end

------------------------------------------java----------------------------------

public class Ex_mainJava {

```
public static void main(String[] args){

    DBPoolCon db = DBPoolCon.getInstance();

    String str = "{call xxx_xxx_xxxx_xxxx_result_pkg.XX_XX_result(?,?,?)}";
try {
    Connection oracleConn   = (OracleConnection) db.buildPoolConnection();
    CallableStatement callStatement = oracleConn.prepareCall(str);

    Object[][] x_ctr_tbl =  new Object[1][16]; 


        x_ctr_tbl[0][0] = 1;   
        x_ctr_tbl[0][1] = 2;
        x_ctr_tbl[0][2] = 3;
        x_ctr_tbl[0][3] = "ABC";
        x_ctr_tbl[0][4] = 4;
        x_ctr_tbl[0][5] = java.sql.Date.valueOf("2014-06-18");
        x_ctr_tbl[0][6] = "DEF";
        x_ctr_tbl[0][7] = 5;
        x_ctr_tbl[0][8] = java.sql.Date.valueOf("2014-06-18");
        x_ctr_tbl[0][9] = 6;
        x_ctr_tbl[0][10] = java.sql.Date.valueOf("2014-06-18");
        x_ctr_tbl[0][11] = 7;
        x_ctr_tbl[0][12] = "HHHH";
        x_ctr_tbl[0][13] = "KKKK";
        x_ctr_tbl[0][14] = "JJJJ";
        x_ctr_tbl[0][15] = "MMMM";



    ArrayDescriptor oracleCollection2 = ArrayDescriptor.createDescriptor("XXXXXXXXXXX_TBL ".toUpperCase(),oracleConn);


    ARRAY oraArry2 =  new ARRAY(oracleCollection2, oracleConn,x_ctr_tbl);
            System.out.println(oraArry2.dump());

    callStatement.registerOutParameter(1, java.sql.Types.VARCHAR);
    callStatement.registerOutParameter(2, java.sql.Types.INTEGER);
    callStatement.setArray(3,oraArry2);
    callStatement.execute();

    String s =callStatement.getString(1);
    int i = callStatement.getInt(2);

        System.out.println("error:"+s);
        System.out.println("code:"+i);

    callStatement.close();






} catch (SQLException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
}

}
```

}

---------console-----------------------------------

```
  System.out.println(oraArry2.dump());    
 nnnnnnn1                1
,nnnnnnn2                2
,nnnnnnn3                3
vvvvvvv1                ??? <---problem
nnnnnnn4                4 
dddddddd1               2014-06-18 00:00:00.0
vvvvvvv2                ??? <---problem
nnnnnnn5                5
dddddddd2               2014-06-18 00:00:00.0
nnnnnnn6                6
 dddddddd3               2014-06-18 00:00:00.0
 nnnnnnn7                7
 vvvvvvv3                ???  <---problem
 vvvvvvv4                ???  <---problem
 vvvvvvv5                ???  <---problem
 vvvvvvv6                ???  <---problem
```

---

EXAMPLE CODE SOURCE

please help me to problem of ??? (problem)

Thank you.
you read my source for my problem

Comment: I find it solve way 
ojdbc6 fit file
Recently orai18n.jar file download in oracle si